# asp.net mvc 3 Remote validation problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my Model :

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email required!")]
    [Remote("EmailExists","User",ErrorMessage = "Email already")]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
```

View :

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult EmailExists(string Email)
    {
         return Json(!Email.Equals("teste@gmail.com"), 
                                      JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` are added. And `web.config` is configured as well.

When I type on Email input it fires `EmailExists` fine. Returns true/false as well. **But it nevers shows the ErrorMessage**

And I get this error :

```
 Erro: uncaught exception: 
 [Exception... "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative"
 nsresult: "0x80570034 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_MODIFY_PROP_ON_WN)"  
 location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/autocomplete.xml ::
 onxblpopuphiding :: line 848"  data: no]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in your description that supposes a problem. I've created a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the default template, added the model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email required!")]
    [Remote("EmailExists", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Email already")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

updated the `HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult EmailExists(string Email)
    {
        return Json(
            !Email.Equals("teste@gmail.com"), 
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        );
    }
}
```

and the `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Validation fires fine and correct error messages are shown (tested with Chrome 10.0, IE9 and FireFox 4.0). So the question now is how does your scenario differs than this one?

Comment: Thanks Darin... I found the problem... It was jquery.validate version... I was using jquery 1.5.1 and jquery.validate 1.7... So I updated to 1.8 and all worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email required!")]
    [Remote("EmailExists","User")]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
```

and

```
    public JsonResult EmailExists(string Email)
    {
        string errorMessage = "Email already";
        if (!Email.Equals("teste@gmail.com"))
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return Json(errorMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```